# Painting a QGraphicsItem based on the QGraphicsView it is displayed in

Tags: qt, image-processing, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I am writing an image processing application in Qt5. The imagery is natievly 16-bit colordepth, and needs to be adjusted to 8-bit for display.

In the normal case, I analyze the data currently visible in the `QGraphicsView` and create a dynamic map to optimally display those pixels.  This is done every time the viewport moves in any way. This map is associated with the `QGraphicsView`.

I've subclassed `QGraphicsScene`, `QGraphicsView`, and `QGraphicsPixmapItem` along the way.

My first attempt was to update the `QGraphicsPixmapItem`'s pixmap whenever the histogram got recalculated, but that doesn't work because the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` might be visible in several views... there is no way to access the view normally.

My second attempt was to override the `QGraphicPixmapItem`'s `paint` method, which does know which view it is painting on, and apply the map then (similar to what `QTransform` does, really, except in colorspace). However, updating the pixmap forces an update, so doing it inside the `paint` method would produce constant painting.

My third attempt was to rip the `setPixmap` function out of the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and implement a version without the update to use right before painting, but of course it accesses private members that I can't in a subclass.

The remaining options I can foresee are all undesireable:

1. Modify QT so that QTransform supports colarspace manipulation *(too much work and I really want a stock QT)*
2. Copy the code for QGraphicsPixmapItem instead of subclassing it, and make it work the way I want *(probably a license issue)*
3. Assume I've only got the one view and just hack it in somewhere.

Am I going about this the entirely wrong way? Is there a QT feature I'm not using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest the following way.

Don't use `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. It doesn't really fits for your goal. Create a subclass of `QGraphicsItem` and perform the painting manually. Enable the `QGraphicsItem::ItemUsesExtendedStyleOption` flag for the item so that `QStyleOptionGraphicsItem::exposedRect` passed to the `paint` method is real exposed rectangle. Set the view's `viewportUpdateMode` to `QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate`. The view will repaint all viewport any time a scroll is moved and call `paint` method of visible graphics item. In the `paint` method implementation you can do any logic you wish. For example, you can construct new `QPixmap` object (or update existing one) and paint it using `QPainter::drawPixmap`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable... I'm not really using much from QGraphicsPixmapItem. I'm about to get on a 14 hour plane ride; hopefully I'll have this done at the end.

Comment: Yep, that was very simple and direct. Thanks